# How to write a digit using XmlDocument in c#?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am trying to create **XML** file and write some data to it.

But I have a problem. I do not know how to write a value in this file. (I think writing a `string` must be OK)

Here is my code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Data", string.Empty);
doc.AppendChild(element1);
for (int i = 0; i < Program.Number; ++i)
{
    XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Block", string.Empty);
    doc.AppendChild(element2);
    XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "ID", string.Empty);
    element3.AppendChild(i); //Compilator gives error there
    element2.AppendChild(element3);
    XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Name", string.Empty);
    XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode(Colegue<string>.Name[i]);
    element4.AppendChild(text2);
    element2.AppendChild(element4)
}
doc.Save(Program.FileName);
```

I must get something like this after work of my program:

```
<Data>
    <Block>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Name>Rob</Name>
    </Block>
    <Block>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
    </Block>
</Data>
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: what is the current value compared to the desired value?

Comment: I mean i do not know how to write a digit in Xml.
For example, i must write a int i = 0 to ID during first "for" iteration.

Comment: Your compiler gives error because `XmlElement.AppendChild()` method expects an `XmlNode`. But you are giving it an integer. I have given a working sample as answer. Check it out..Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XmlDocument` this way:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> Colleagues = new List<string>() { "Rob", "Peter"};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("Data");
        doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            XmlNode blockNode = doc.CreateElement("Block");
            XmlNode idNode = doc.CreateElement("ID");
            idNode.InnerText = i.ToString();
            blockNode.AppendChild(idNode);
            XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            nameNode.InnerText = Colleagues[i];
            blockNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
            rootNode.AppendChild(blockNode);
        }
        doc.Save("XmlDocument.xml");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Data>
  <Block>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Name>Rob</Name>
  </Block>
  <Block>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
  </Block>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you class serialization.

Make classes that reflect your data structure and serialize it. For example, classes can be like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlArray("Blocks")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Block")]
    public List<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Block
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Attribute `XmlRoot` tells serializer how to name root element while         `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` control how will list of Blocks and Block element will be serialized. 
When you fill your classes, just serialize them to xml.

```
Data data = new Data();
data.Blocks = new List<Block>();
data.Blocks.Add(new Block() { ID = 0, Name = "Rob" });
data.Blocks.Add(new Block() { ID = 1, Name = "Peter" });
data.Blocks.Add(new Block() { ID = 2, Name = "Mary" });

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("c:\\test.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xs.Serialize(stream, data);
}
```

resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Blocks>
    <Block>
      <Name>Rob</Name>
      <ID>0</ID>
    </Block>
    <Block>
      <Name>Peter</Name>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </Block>
    <Block>
      <Name>Mary</Name>
      <ID>2</ID>
    </Block>
  </Blocks>
</Data>
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. 
I know about serialisation and i think that it is much convinient than XmlDocument stuff but my code of program will not be approved in my university because using of serialisation stuff is denied by professor

Comment: @tank0412 No problem, I'm glad you solved your problem, thanks to Abhishek.